# Zend Framework 2 Installation Improper

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I installed zend framework 2 using the skeleton. Basically, followed the steps mentioned in https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication#using-composer-recommended

To Summarize, I followed below commands:

```
cd my/project/dir
git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git
cd ZendSkeletonApplication
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar install
```

After this I added Virtual Host has mentioned in the link above and added entry in /etc/hosts.

And now, when I access the link i.e zendemo.com instead of directing me to Welcome page, I see the index.php script. Any pointers what do I neeed to do?

OS: Ubuntu 13.10
Php version: PHP 5.5.3

Comment: what does virtual host config look like?

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>  
        ServerName zendemo.com  
        DocumentRoot /var/www/zendapp/ZendSkeletonApplication/public  
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"  
        <Directory /var/www/zendapp/ZendSkeletonApplication/public>  
           DirectoryIndex index.php  
           AllowOverride All  
           Order allow,deny  
           Allow from all  
        </Directory>  
    </VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the Apache `mod_rewrite` module? Try running the `a2enmod rewrite` command from your command shell and then restart Apache.

Comment: That was the first thing that I did when I had a doubt that it could be mod_rewrite issue.